# opencv build github actions

Tags: maven, spring-boot, opencv, github-actions

In my spring boot project, I'm using `OpenCV` which depends on native `c++` library for `OpenCV`. While development and testing I've built those native libs in my system.

Unit test cases related to `OpenCV` are also supposed to run with every push in a PR.

Building `OpenCV` takes close to 20 minutes. I'm not sure if running that on every commit is feasible.

Can someone please tell me what is the way to achieve this?

We are using `GitHub` actions for CI. So all this `OpenCV` build happens in `GitHub` provided VM.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the following question is also applicable here I think.
[Need to set environment in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58281558/need-to-set-environment-in-github-actions/58315661#58315661)

The solution is to create a Docker image that pre-installs the native c++ libraries that you need. Then when executing your unit test cases, use the `container` setting for a `job` so that the unit test steps execute in the context of your pre-built image.

This is the documentation for the `container` syntax.
https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer

Comment: Can we run everything in the workflow inside a container? Starting from checkout?

Comment: I haven't tested myself, but from my understanding of the documentation, all `run` script steps of the `job` will execute in the context of the image specified in the `container` attribute. Container based actions will execute as sibling containers on the same network with the same volume mounts. So my assumption is that, yes, it should work for all steps starting from checkout. Try it out yourself and if you run into any trouble you could create a new question.

Comment: I'll try this and update you on the same! Thanks for the help.